# how to extent range of interpolation?

Tags: python, interpolation

I am creating an interpolated map of temperature with python, based on pointy lat,lon,temperature data. It is ok but I would like to extent a few the area of interpolation: as you can see in the picture, there are two small white areas that I would like to cover. The points of measure are showed on the map. It follows my code:

[image]

```
import geopandas as gpd
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
#from scipy.interpolate import CloughTocher2DInterpolator
#from scipy.interpolate import interpn
#from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline
#from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Caricamento dei dati dal file CSV
data = pd.read_csv('./dati_meteolazio.csv')
punti_lazio = pd.read_csv('../gis/punti_lazio_500m.csv')
punti_lazio[punti_lazio < -10] = np.nan
punti_lazio = punti_lazio.dropna(subset=['Value'])

data['timestamp_utc'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp_utc'], unit='s')

# Calcola l'orario attuale
now = datetime.now()

# Calcola l'orario massimo fino a 30 minuti fa rispetto all'orario attuale
time_threshold = now - timedelta(minutes=300)

# Seleziona i dati con 'timestamp_utc' fino a 30 minuti fa
df = data[data['timestamp_utc'] >= time_threshold]

df['tempnorm'] = df['temperatura'] + 0.0065 * df['quota_slm']

# variabile da interpolare
var_interp = 'tempnorm'

# Caricamento dei dati dagli shapefile del Lazio
strade_lazio_con_roma = gpd.read_file('../gis/strade_lazio_con_Roma.shp')
province_lazio = gpd.read_file('../gis/Province_Lazio_4326.shp')
mare = gpd.read_file('../gis/mare.shp')

# Limiti della regione del Lazio
#lazio_extents = [11.3522413181166417, 41.0954633593770779, 14.0852054633171981, 42.9709989784695949]
lazio_extents = [11.4325800981783932,41.1968069281675184, 14.0373950944891845,42.8694625525826680]

# Seleziona le colonne necessarie dal DataFrame per l'interpolazione
data_for_interpolation = df[['latitudine', 'longitudine', var_interp]].copy()  # Copia i dati per evitare SettingWithCopyWarning

# Rimuovi le righe con valori mancanti
data_for_interpolation.dropna(subset=['latitudine', 'longitudine', var_interp], inplace=True)

# Converti i dati in array numpy per l'interpolazione
lat = data_for_interpolation['latitudine'].values
lon = data_for_interpolation['longitudine'].values
var0 = data_for_interpolation[var_interp].values

# Trova i limiti estremi della griglia per l'interpolazione nel Lazio
min_lon, min_lat, max_lon, max_lat = lazio_extents
xi = np.linspace(min_lon, max_lon, 500)
yi = np.linspace(min_lat, max_lat, 500)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

zi = griddata((lon, lat), var0, (xi, yi), method='cubic')

elev_interpolated = griddata((punti_lazio['Longitude'], punti_lazio['Latitude']), punti_lazio['Value'], (xi, yi), method='cubic')

var = zi - 0.0065 * elev_interpolated

vmin = -20
vmax = 45

# Creazione della mappa
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 10), dpi=200)  # Imposta la grandezza e la risoluzione dell'immagine

# Plottaggio della mappa interpolata di temperatura con limiti definiti per il Lazio
c = ax.contourf(xi, yi, var, levels=65, cmap='turbo', extent=lazio_extents, vmin = vmin, vmax = vmax)

# Plottaggio delle isolinee di temperatura ogni 1 grado
iso = ax.contour(xi, yi, var, levels=range(vmin, vmax+1, 2), colors='grey', extent=lazio_extents, linewidths=0.7, alpha=0.7)

# Etichettatura delle isolinee ogni 2 gradi
ax.clabel(iso, inline=True, fontsize=7, colors='black',zorder=1)


# Plottaggio degli shapefile del Lazio
if 'strade_lazio_con_roma' in locals():  # Verifica se lo shapefile è stato caricato correttamente
    strade_lazio_con_roma.plot(ax=ax, color='blue', linewidth=0.5)

if 'province_lazio' in locals():  # Verifica se lo shapefile è stato caricato correttamente
    province_lazio.plot(ax=ax, color='none', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.5)
    

# Resto del tuo codice per il plottaggio degli shapefile e l'impostazione della mappa...

# Caricamento e plottaggio dell'area al di fuori del Lazio in grigio
italia_senza_lazio = gpd.read_file('../gis/Italia_senza_Lazio_4326.shp')
italia_senza_lazio.plot(ax=ax, color='lightgrey', zorder=2)
mare.plot(ax=ax, color='blue', zorder=2)
plt.scatter(lat, lon, color='red', marker='o', label='Stazioni Meteo', s=20, zorder=3)
plt.plot(lon, lat, 'ro', markersize=2, label='Stazioni Meteo')

# Aggiunta della barra dei colori per la temperatura con valori specifici
cbar = plt.colorbar(c, ax=ax, label='Temperatura', ticks=[vmin, vmax])

# Aggiunta della barra dei colori per la temperatura
#cbar = plt.colorbar(c, ax=ax, label='Temperatura')

# Impostazioni della mappa
ax.set_title('Mappa Interpolata di Temperatura nel Lazio')
ax.set_xlabel('Longitudine')
ax.set_ylabel('Latitudine')
# ax.legend(['Strade Lazio con Roma', 'Province Lazio'])

# Applicazione dello zoom all'area di interesse
ax.set_xlim([min_lon, max_lon])
ax.set_ylim([min_lat, max_lat])

plt.savefig('mappa_temperatura_elevazione.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')  # 'bbox_inches' aiuta a evitare tagli degli assi
plt.show()
```

Comment: Interpolation by definition is for the space between points. You'll notice that the white areas are outside the envelope of your points.  What you want is extrapolation, an entirely different process.

Comment: I understand what you say. But for example, with NCL interpolation codes I didn't have this problem with the same set of points.